# Searching alorithm that accounts for mistakes

Tags: c#, search

I'm still a noob at working with data so I don't know where to look for more advanced algorithms. Where can I find the info about a string searching algorithm that doesn't require exact input?

I want to make a little programm that works pretty much like this: there are quotes and tags asociated with them, a random tag appears and the user has to input a quote that might be compatible with it, my lil programm searches if it has the quote, returns true or false and shows you the number of mistakes.

Here's what i've done so far

```cs
    public readonly struct Quote
    {
        public readonly string[] Tags;
        public readonly string TheQuote;

        public Quote(string theQuote, params string[] tags)
        {
            Tags = tags;
            TheQuote = theQuote;
        }
    }

       static void MatchTag()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a quote that might fit the tag");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var inpL = input.Length;
            var allowedMistakes = 5;

            var possibleQuotes = quotes.Where(q => q.Tags.Contains(currTag) && inpL.IsInRange(q.TheQuote.Length, q.TheQuote.Length < 10 ? 2 : q.TheQuote.Length / 10));
            foreach (var quote in possibleQuotes)
            {
                var quoteTxt = quote.TheQuote;

                int diff = quoteStr.Length - inpL, length, mistakesNum=0;
                if (diff < 0)//go through the smallest string to not throw an error
                {
                    length = quoteTxt.Length;
                    mistakesNum += -diff;
                }
                else
                    length = inpL;

                bool clear = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (input[i] != quoteTxt[i])
                        mistakesNum++;
                    if (mistakesNum > allowedMistakes)
                    {
                        clear = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if (clear)
                    continue;

                //show that you are right and return;
                Console.WriteLine("The quote fits the tag!");
                Console.WriteLine("Mistakes: " + mistakesNum);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The quote doesn't fit the tag!");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exact input"? It could be anything from casing difference to AI that figures out what was meant instead. My first thought would be "fuzzy matching", but you need to clarify your requirement

Comment: Is the point to implement this kind of algorithm yourself? Or just get a working solution? Because there are Nuget packages for fuzzy string search etc.

Comment: This is not really text search. Instead you compare a quote (string) with a fixed set of quotes (strings). You have a pool of strings and now you have to check if this pool contains the string that was input by the user. The pool should be a HashSet<string> for faster lookup. You probably have to provide a custom IEqualityComparer via the constructor to make the lookup case insensitive.

Comment: Also, you would simplify the lookup by creating a corresponding table (Dictionary<K,V>) that maps a tag to its associated string (quote). If you want you can step through this string character by character (or word by word if that makes more sense) and compare it to the input and e.g. color non-matching characters/words red. This solution is the simplest and doesn't require a lookup pool. It simply depends on a table that maps a tag to the correct string (quote).

Comment: @UnholySheep the opposite of exact input would be: an input with punctuation errors, casing errors, misspellings and other small mistakes

Comment: @marsze if the algorithm is begginer friendly, then I wouldn't mind trying to implement it by myself. Thanks for the ideea though, I didn't know the name of this concept and now I know where to look

Comment: @BionicCode Yeah but the problem appears when the user makes mistakes. The tags shouldn't be unique to each quote and if the input has some misspells, I don't know how to find the match

Comment: First, you can map a single tag (dictionary key) to a list of strings (dictionary values). You must understand that such a table significantly reduces the costs of your algorithm: you no longer have to compare the input to ALL references. This table is not the problem. If your task is to find the errors in the user's input to highlight them so that the user can correct those errors, the task is simple. If you want to detect misspelling and ambiguities and still want to accept the input if it semantically correct, the solution is highly complex and really difficult.

Comment: Generally, if you don't require exact matches, there will always be the edge cases where you accept the wrong input. Because your input is a complete text you would have to check grammar too. For example "man" and "men" could both be accepted. You need to make rules first.

Comment: 1. rule: do I only care about semantics alone? For example *quoting* has very strict rules. In order to be identified as a quote the input has to match more than only semantics. 2. rule: not every word is required to match. For example, we can apply a desired degree of simplification. 3. rule: to reduce the required effort, typos in required words are not accepted and must be fixed by the user. To implement the 1. rule you can remove some constraints by reducing the number of required valid matches. This is called sentence reduction.

Comment: You reduce the sentence to a degree where the information is still expressed. For example: *"A bad workman always blames his tools."*. You can safely ignore: any punctuation, adjectives, indefinite articles and articles, probably adverbs. You get: *"workman blames his tools"*.  This allows for typos in all the ignored words.

Comment: Now that you have your bag with constraints that are possible to ignore, you can apply those rules to each individual answer: create a dictionary of correct answers that you use for display. Map this correct answer to a dictionary of reduced answers that you use for matching. If the input still doesn't match your reduced or minimal acceptable input, you flag the errors and allow the user to correct them. Additionally use a spellchecker for the input field to improve the input quality.

Comment: You must understand that full text input always involves grammar and semantics analysis. You would check for word substitutes like a Thesaurus. This means you have to resolve ambiguities with any word in a text. Now you should understand that your problem is not solved by a simple text search. Even more, if you want to avoid to input the reduced match predicate manually you need a sort of linguistic AI to automate the process.

Comment: I don't know about your project. But I guess you have two options: 1) find a linguistic AI which you very likely have to pay for 2) loosen your restrictions by requiring the input to "exactly" match the reference. You can apply different degrees of reduction to increase the likeliness of a match when the input provides a degree ambiguity and errors. Like ignoring punctuation an casing is the smallest degree of reduction.

Comment: Take a look at the auto-correct and auto-suggest/auto-complete feature of your smartphone. It appears to trivial. But now check the errors it produces. The Google algorithm is quite good and still regularly fails to successfully auto-complete. You need to combine all those algorithms. That's why I suggested to look for a commercial solution. Most services charge you for a certain contingent of requests.

Comment: Depending on your goals, you are going to touch a very interesting but complex topic. Like complex mathematical algorithms require a high degree of mathematical knowledge, a complex linguistic algorithm requires a high degree of linguistic knowledge. You need this knowledge before you can even start to think about the algorithm itself. In other words, you need to be able to fully understand the problem in order to be able to solve it. If you lack this knowledge, you can gain it or find an existing solution. If you are short in time, using an existing solution is the only option.

Comment: Or simplify the requirements. Hardcoding and maintaining a table of reduced match references is a good/sufficient? option too (see suggestion above).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much @BionicCode. Your tips are very valuable to me. I will simplify the requirements (ignore casing, punctuation misstakes) and if the program won't find any matching quote, then I will display all the quotes that contain the same 'keywords' so the user can choose the one he tried to input

Comment: Sounds like a very legit solution. Good luck with your project.